# Define size of aliased column

Tags: mysql, sql, database, calculated-columns

So i have a query, something like this :

```
select (0.25*tugas)+(0.25*uts)+(0.5*uas) as nilai_akhir from nilai;
```

And sometime the result is too long, for example like this : 7.050000

Can we define the size of the aliased column to something like this : 7.05 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ROUND(), CEIL() or FLOOR() function which will truncate your result in the format you want.

```
select Round((0.25*tugas)+(0.25*uts)+(0.5*uas),2) as nilai_akhir from nilai;
```